# Remove a node in LinkedList in Java given the node reference

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

For example, if I have LinkedList

```
LinkedList<Integer> ll = new LinkedList<Integer>（）；
ll.add(1);
ll.add(2);
ll.add(3);
Integer x = new Integer(10);
ll.add(x);
ll.add(4);
// now the list looks like 1->2->3->10->4

// what if I want to remove 10 and I still have the reference to that node x
// what is the API of that
// somethings like ll.remove(x)...
```

If I implement a doubly linked list by myself, just

```
currentNode.prev.next = currentNode.next;
currentNode.next.prev = currentNode.prev;
```

Does Java's implementation of LinkedList support this operation?

Comment: You never added `x` to your list.

Comment: your linked list would be 1->2->3->4 because you never add 10 to it

Comment: What do you mean by _"I still have the reference to that node x"_ ?
Do you mean after deleting 'x' you still need a reference to 'x' or you mean you just have a reference to 'x' and you wish to delete that

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add x, edited again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pointer into Java LinkedList Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294241/pointer-into-java-linkedlist-node)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe its just a copy paste error that you forgot to add the node x to your linked list. Assuming your correct code is like this:

```
Integer x = new Integer(10);
ll.add(x);
ll.add(4);
```

You can remove a node from java LinkedList using `remove(Object o)` method. So call that to remove node `x` from linkedlist `ll`.

```
ll.remove(x); //removes x from linkedlist but does not delete object x
```

It will remove `x` from the linkedlist but object `x` is still alive in your code and usable anywhere else.

Comment: Note that this is an O(n) operation. `java.util.LinkedList` does not expose its internal nodes, so the only way to remove an element in constant time is while iterating over the list. This makes LinkedList#removeIf trivially O(n), but provides no benefit over ArrayList when removing a single element.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#remove%28int%29).

For `java.util.LinkedList<E>`

> `public E remove(int index)`
>
> Removes the element at the specified position in this list. Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices). Returns the element that was removed from the list.

there's also a `remove(Object x)` that does the same but for a specific object, not an index.

Is that what you were looking for?